# programmatically create a new Xtext project

Tags: java, eclipse, command-line-interface, xtext, programmatically-created

I need to programmatically create a new Xtext project, or better, I need to automate the "New Xtext Project" eclipse wizard and run it from a command line standalone java application.
Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the code that does the creation is basically independent from eclipse ui. have a look at this test: https://github.com/eclipse/xtext-core/blob/master/org.eclipse.xtext.tests/src/org/eclipse/xtext/xtext/wizard/cli/CliWizardIntegrationTest.xtend